# MySQL: Fastes Query to check if a state is set

Tags: mysql

I have following table in MySQL:

## id (pk) | objId | state

Now I want to check for "objId=X", if ...

1. There is at least one record, which has "state=1"
2. Or there are no records at all.

My only solution is this (but its seems overkill):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), state
FROM tblObj
WHERE objId = 12552
GROUP BY state;
```

And then, in PHP I check, if there is "state=3" or there are no results at all.

Is there a better/faster way to do it in MySQL?

Thank you guys!

Comment: what do you expect as a result set?

Comment: I don´t have to be true/false - its okay, if I can check it in PHP after I get the result. Should just not kill the performance, because the query will be executed a lot of times on a big table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly:

```
select count(*) from tblObj where objId = 12552 and state = 1;
```

In this case try something like this:

```
select count(case when state != 1 then NULL else 1 end) as cnt, count(*) as cnt_total
from tblObj 
where objId = 12552;
```

PS i didn't test it so you might need to debug it...

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for you reply.  Not exactly: If there are no records, I want to get "true", or at least somehow check in PHP. But if there are records, but just with some other state (like 2, 3, 4) but no record with a state 1, that its a "false".

Comment: Thank you very much! The current version is working fine (when 'cnt' will be 0, i´ll check if 'cnt_total' is 0 to). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you

```
 select count(*) AS count , tp.state from tblObj AS tp 
  where objId = 12552 and state in( '1', '0');
```

Comment: I get a syntax error (and not sure what to change): Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''to'

Comment: updated alias now try this. it was considering to as a key word